# What does square brackets on their own represent?

Tags: python, arrays, q-learning

Hi I'm just working with adapting some python code and making sure I understand everything within it as I've never really worked with Python before. What does the [0] alone mean in the code mean? (qtable is 2 dimensional array, holding states(s) and actions(a), actions is a list, current_s is an integer)

`self.q_table[current_s] = ([0] * len(self.actions))`

Comment: list with only one element. multiplying by len provides a vector of zeroes

Comment: or in other words list of 0s, brackets in python are very important, slicing, accessing dict keys, indices, list shortcuts, accessing individual chars(strings) etc.

Comment: To find out simple things like this for your self, I find that: `print([], type([]))` is quite revealing, output: `[] <class 'list'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[0]` is a `list` with one element: zero.

Then the program uses `*` operator (list multiplication in this case) to replicate the left operand list `len(self.actions)` times.

This creates a list of zeroes of `len(self.actions)` length.

With immutable types, that is the preferred initialization. A slower alternative (which *must* be used for mutable types) would be:

```
[0 for _ in len(self.actions)]
```

Comment: Perfect thankyou, I thought it was just the value 0 and couldn't understand why it was being multiplied by that. Makes a lot of sense with the rest of the code now :)